# How to remove single quotes from resultant query due to parameter binding in GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I want to create a schema in PostgreSQL using GORM. I'm currently doing it as follows -

```
err = db.Exec("CREATE SCHEMA ?", *org.Name).Error;
```

The following is the resulting query -

```
 CREATE SCHEMA 'org1'
```

I get the error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" (SQLSTATE 42601)

However the valid way to create is a schema in PostgreSQL is either

```
CREATE SCHEMA org1
```

or

```
CREATE SCHEMA "org1"
```

`*org.Name` is obtained from the user. How do I create a query in either of the above manner while also securing against any injection attack ?

Comment: Did you import right driver for postgres?

Comment: @rosmak yes, I'm using gorm.io/driver/postgres

Comment: Parameter placeholders are for __values__, NOT for __identifiers__. Unless the standard is being subverted by whatever library you're using, you cannot use `?` nor `$N` for identifiers like table names, column names, schema names, etc.

Comment: @mkopriva So how would you prepare the sql identifier when there is a need to provide the sql identifier by external input?

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue. I solved it by using `pq.QuoteIdentifier(*org.Name)` provided by `"github.com/lib/pq"`.

It is the standard when using the postgres driver. Then you could just use a raw query to execute your query. See full example:

```
err = db.Exec("CREATE SCHEMA " + pq.QuoteIdentifier(*org.Name)).Error;
```